# Magento 2 - Can you replace any observer with plugin?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

I am using a observer for the event **sales_order_place_before**.

It does not work as expected, so I try to replace it with a plugin to see if it does make a difference.

The event *sales_order_place_before* is dispatched here:

**vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order.php**

```
public function place()
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_before', ['order' => $this]);
    $this->_placePayment();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_after', ['order' => $this]);
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see the parameter "order" is passed to the observer.

How can I access the **order** parameter from a plugin? Is it even possible?

---

I tried the code from @Amit Bera:

```
public function  beforePlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $logger->info("Hello from beforePlace plugin!");
    $logger->info("Order ID:");
    $logger->info($order->getId());
}
```

**Output:**

```
> 1: Hello from beforePlace plugin! 
> 2: Order ID: 
> 3:
```

Line 3 is empty

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: You can't get id before placing an order. Try after place plugin.

Comment: @SohelRana, I also tried afterPlace but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService">
    <plugin name="orderservice_place_order_plugin" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\OrderService"/>
</type>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/OrderService.php**

```
public function afterPlace(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $subject,
    $result
) {

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have to unaccept again. I figured out that if the plugin is enabled, then I always get redirected to the cart after placing the order, even when the plugin is doing nothing but logging someting to a logfile

Comment: Change the variable name

Comment: The problem was not the variable name, the problem was that I missed the `return $order`, I was not aware that we have to return it to make it work, so I removed it... my fault sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can get order object to  **after, before,around** Plugin.

If you check  plugin concept the then you can see the first param of the plugin obviously current class/interface object, So you can get order info easily on plugin like event & observer

Let me explain, Suppose, you have defined before plugin on place() function

then  before the plugin look like

```
    public function  beforePlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject)
    {
      $order = $subject;
...
    }
```

For your case, `place()`  method does not call that  why `sales_order_place_before`  event does not fire.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work. See my updatet quesiton please. Thx